# List loses the last item in List C

Tags: c++

I've got a problem with this code..... Reading method works fine but everything "crashes" when I want to add new item to my one direction list, and adding this item relies on evertything is sorted ascending. The items in file are sorted ascending for short cut. It works but not fully and I even draw everythink on a paper to follow my code and I have no idea why it loses the last item in list when I'm trying to print all list on the screen. Please, help me to solve that problem. Code below is mixed with C and C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
using namespace std;

int howManyRecords = 0;   // how many record readed from file


struct pojazd 
{
    char model[40];   // Name of the vechicle
    int yearOfProduction;  // Year of production
    float engineCapacity;   // capacity of the engine
    struct pojazd *nast;  // pointer for the next element
};
struct pojazd* creatingNewItem()  // method creating new object of this structure for later adding it to list
{
    struct pojazd *tmpVechicle=NULL;

    tmpVechicle = (struct pojazd*)malloc(sizeof(struct pojazd));

 // MODEL, YEAR AND CAPACITY OF THE ENGINE
 /////////////////
    cout << "Zaraz podasz dane nowego pojazdu. Przygotuj sie." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Podaj model samochodu: "; cin >> tmpVechicle->model; cout << endl;
    cout << "Podaj rok produkcji samochodu: "; cin >> tmpVechicle->yearOfProduction; cout << endl;
    cout << "Podaj pojemnosc silnika samochodu: "; cin >> tmpVechicle->engineCapacity; cout << endl;

    tmpVechicle->nast = NULL;

    cout<<"Model:"<< tmpVechicle->model<<" rok:" << tmpVechicle->yearOfProduction << " pojemosc:" << tmpVechicle->engineCapacity <<endl;

    return tmpVechicle;

}


//Adding new created item to the list using pointers to list and new item
// Adding it to the list keeping ascending politic.

void addingNewItemToList(struct pojazd *headList, struct pojazd *newItem)
{

    struct pojazd *pomocnicza = NULL, *head = NULL;

    head = headList->nast;
    pomocnicza = headList;

    while(true)
    {


            if( (pomocnicza->yearOfProduction < newItem->yearOfProduction) && (newItem->yearOfProduction < head->yearOfProduction))
            {
                pomocnicza->nast = newItem;
                newItem->nast = head;
                break;
            }
            else if((head->nast == NULL) && (pomocnicza->yearOfProduction < newItem->yearOfProduction))
            {
                pomocnicza->nast = newItem;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                pomocnicza = head;
                head = head->nast;
            }
    }

}

 // READING FROM FILE AND ALLOCATING NEW OBJECT OF LIST
 /////////////////////////
struct pojazd* uzupelnianieListy(FILE *odczytywanie)
{


    struct pojazd *beggining = NULL,*nextElement = NULL;

    while (!feof(odczytywanie))
    {
        if (beggining == NULL)
        {
            beggining = nextElement = (struct pojazd*)malloc(sizeof(struct pojazd));
        }
        else
        {
            nextElement->nast = (struct pojazd*)malloc(sizeof(struct pojazd));
            nextElement = nextElement->nast;
        }

        fscanf(odczytywanie, "%s %d %f", nextElement->model, &(nextElement->yearOfProduction), &(nextElement->engineCapacity));
        cout << nextElement->model << endl;
        cout << nextElement->yearOfProduction << endl;
        cout << nextElement->engineCapacity << endl;

        cout << "\n";
        nextElement->nast = NULL;

        howManyRecords++;
        cout<< howManyRecords <<endl;

    }
    fclose(odczytywanie);//closing pliku

    system("pause");

    return beggining;

}


int main()
{
// INPUT OUTPUT FILE
    char wejscie[20], wyjscie[20];

    FILE* odczytywanie;
    FILE *zapisywanie;
//HEAD OF THE LIST
    struct pojazd *headList = NULL;
//NEW ITEM POINTER
    struct pojazd *newItem = NULL;

//ADDITIONAL POINTER IN PRINTING CODE at THE BOTTOM
    struct pojazd *helper = NULL;


    cout << "Podaj nazwe pliku do odczytu: "; cin >> wejscie;
    odczytywanie = fopen(wejscie, "r");




    headList = uzupelnianieListy(odczytywanie);


    newItem = creatingNewItem(); // Creating new Item

    addingNewItemToList(headList, newItem);

    helper = headList;

  /// NEW LIST OF ITEMS
  ////
    cout << "*************************Nowa lista*********************" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < howManyRecords; i++)
    {

        cout << helper->model << endl;
        cout << helper->yearOfProduction << endl;
        cout << helper->engineCapacity << endl;

        helper = helper->nast;

    }
    cout << "*************************koniec Nowa lista*********************" << endl;


    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a file with contents:

```
// NAME YEAR CAPACITY

Syrena 1977 650
Maluch 1999 3800
Polonez 2004 1774
```

What is wrong with that program....?

Comment: just a comment: do not use polish identifier names. It highly discourages non polish speakers to even look at the code.

Comment: This may sound a bit smug, but to raise your chances of getting help onwards - write the code in english :) I'm having a hard time following the flow since the variable names are gibberish to me. What is that - polish ? :)

Comment: Sure give me a minute to rewrite it.

Comment: In `dodawanieDoListy` function `head = poczatek->nast;` can be NULL.. Then you check `head->rok_produkcji` which give you a crash. The same problem may occur on the next iterations of while loop also.

Comment: That also I know but i really do not know why it loses (not crashes) last item of the list. I'm asking anyone here to help me solve it. Code is refactored.

Comment: @Darek since you are using dynamic memory allocation, a one-off error where you lose the last element should be detectable as a memory leak using `valgrind` ?

Comment: C has no namespaces, and the `<<` operator does not allow char* arguments. Died you mean C++ ?

Comment: @joop if you bothered to read the question in its entirety, you had stumbled upon this passage: `Code below is mixed with C and C++.` :)

Comment: @Morten, I believe joop talked about tags.

Comment: I select only on tags (intending to ignore c++). Tagging correctly will avoid wasting time for me and probably a few others, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't increment `ileRekordow` in `dodawanieDoListy`, when you add a new record.
(or this is `howManyRecords` in `addingNewItemToList` in your new code)

Here is the example, how it should be:

```
void addingNewItemToList(struct pojazd **headList, struct pojazd *newItem)
{

    struct pojazd *pomocnicza = NULL, *head = NULL;

    head = (*headList)->nast;
    pomocnicza = *headList;

    while(true)
    {


        if(head == NULL) 
        {
            pomocnicza->nast = newItem;
            break;
        }else if( (pomocnicza->yearOfProduction <= newItem->yearOfProduction) && (newItem->yearOfProduction < head->yearOfProduction))
        {
            pomocnicza->nast = newItem;
            newItem->nast = head;
            break;
        }else if (pomocnicza->yearOfProduction>newItem->yearOfProduction){
            newItem->nast=pomocnicza;
            (*headList)=newItem;
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            pomocnicza = head;
            head = head->nast;
        }
    }
    howManyRecords++;

}
```

Also, because I changed the declaration of this function, it should be called like this:

```
addingNewItemToList(&headList, newItem);
```

Comment: I'm incrementing it and it has value 3.

Comment: @Darek, no you don't. When you add records from file - you increment howManyRecords properly, but when you insert new record from keyboard input - you don't increment howManyRecords, so when you print out results - you don't print last record in list.

Comment: THANK you very much for that. One thing and so many problems :)

Comment: @Darek, I added an example of correct funtion for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your code through a debugger. Chances are it has something to do with pointers.
For example you can use gdb very easily to find the exact line causing a problem :

> gdb your_executable
>
> run
>
> backtrace
>
> f0 (or any other number to see in which part of the code the bug happened)

It'll give you the line that caused the segfault.
You might have to compile with -g to make it work with the debugger.

Also I don't know if it's a requirement to use pointer but the standard library has some data structures with automatic memory management (std::vector, std::list, etc).
If you don't have to use manual allocation (malloc) explicitly it's a better practice when writing c++ to use 1) the stl containers and 2) the new operator if you want to manage memory yourself.

Comment: Yes I know that there are libraries but my teacher asked to do this using elementary structures -.-